# Routing in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

how to convert this routes which is in rails 2 to rails 3

```
%w(a).each do |attr|
    map.resources :b, :name_prefix => "#{attr}_", :path_prefix => "/#{attr.pluralize}/:#{attr}_id"
  end

  map.resources :a do |s|
    s.resources :t do |ts|
      ts.resources :p
      ts.resource :m, :controller => :m
    end
  end
end
```

any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
%w(a).each do |attr|
  resources :b, :name_prefix => "#{attr}_", :path_prefix => "/#{attr.pluralize}/:#{attr}_id"
end

resources :a do
  resources :t do
    resources :p
    resources :m, :controller => :m
  end
end
```

EDIT : as per comment

```
map.resources :q, :name_prefix => 'all_', :collection => { :search => :get }
```

can be written as

```
resources :q, :name_prefix => 'all_' do
  collection do
    get :search
  end
end
```

Something seems off in your pasted code with indentation and an extra end?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response     how to use this routes part in rails 3    for example : map.resources :q, :name_prefix => 'all_', :collection => { :search => :get }